# Es lo mismo decir (etiqueta self-closing) (etiqueta vacía) y (void element)?

Tags: html, html5

Estaba revisando un poco de teoria de html y me encontraba con la duda de llamar a una etiqueta vacía o self-colsing que opino que es lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

No son lo mismo, **etiqueta vacia** se llama a los elementos que no deben tener contenido, como por ejemplo `<hr/>` o `<br/>`. Por otro lado, se llama **self-colsing** a la sintaxis con que indica que un elemento no va a tener contenido, es decir la barra antes de cerrar el tag: `/>`, permite que el interprete HTML no busque una etiqueta de cerrado, ejemplo un para un boton que no lleva texto deberiamos hacer esto `<button></button>`, pero la sintaxis **self-closing** nos permite escribir lo mismo de esta manera: `<button/>`.